# How can I use Zend Paginator and Zend Amazon together?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Is there a straightforward (easy) way to use Zend Framework's Paginator with the Zend Framework Amazon service? It looks like the recordset returned by the Amazon service is not what the Paginator needs.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to test this I'm afraid, but the docs for `Zend_Service_Amazon` state that the result set implements `SeekableIterator` ( http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.service.amazon.html#zend.service.amazon.classes.resultset ) - and that should be compatible with the `Iterator` adapter for `Zend_Paginator`, e.g.:

```
$amazon = new Zend_Service_Amazon(....);
$results = $amazon->itemSearch(array('SearchIndex' => 'Books', 'Keywords' => 'php'));
$paginator = new Zend_Paginator(new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_Iterator($results));
```